# Increase the Daily Limit of Queries while not being a Business Owner

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have wrote a script for google sheet with the help of Chat Gpt that helps me take track of the views, comments, title etc. of some specific Youtube videos on a google sheet. this code is written with the help of a YouTube Data API v3 key. I see there is a max daily limit of 10k Queries per day, with the code that I wrote and the amount of videos I need to check, I easily exceed that max limit, I see that to increase the limit you need to fill out a huge form where you have to talk about your business, insert your website.... I have none of those things, I am a simple user which built a tool and would like to get an higher limit in order to run my tool properly. There is no way for a "normal person" like me to contact the any kind of assistant or anything, which is why I am writing my question here.

I would like to PAY MORE without being a business owner, and INCREASE my daily max limit of Queries for the YouTube API.

I tried contacting the assistance of Google One but they were not able to help as this is not what they are specialized in, I would like to get help from you guys.

Comment: With [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) endpoint you can fetch such fields for 50 * 10,000 = 50,000 videos, do you exceed this limit per day?

Comment: the limit of queries per API key is 10k per day, why are you saying 50* 10,000? and anyway I was looking to have something more like 100k/200k max a day to be safe, today just by testing the tool I reached the limit

Comment: [50 is the maximum number](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#part) of [video ids](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#id) per request. A potentially against ToS alternative is to use my no-key endpoint at https://yt.lemnoslife.com

Comment: would you mind have a chat? I will try to contact you on discord, give me your discord name please

Comment: [Here is my Discord](https://discord.gg/pDzafhGWzf).

Comment: perfect will dm you tomorrow